# Running Python at a Certain Time with Datetime

Tags: python, time

I would like to execute a portion of a script at 8 am each day. I have created a simplified test case that has no syntax error, but does not work properly. I think it may be because my if statement is using the time as a string, but it won't compile any other way. What am I doing wrong?

```
import datetime

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().time()  == "19:00:00.000000":
        print "it's time!"
```

Comment: Why won't you just use cron?

Comment: Not familiar with cron, but this should still work

Comment: Given that you are specific to a millisecond, it may not, as millisecond is very short time and its easy to miss it. Just stick to cron, google can lead you into the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a system with `cron`, then it would be better to set up a cron job. However, your problem is fixable from within Python:

First, as you noted, `datetime.datetime.now().time()` returns a `datetime.time` object, not a string:

```
In [89]: datetime.datetime.now().time()
Out[89]: datetime.time(19, 36, 13, 388625)
```

Also, although `datetime.datetime.now().time() == datetime.time(19, 0)` would be
valid Python, the chance that you happen to execute `time()` at just the right
moment is very slim since `datetime.datetime.now()` has microsecond
resolution. So it would be better to test if the current time falls within some
range.

However, since you only want to run the function once per day, you could instead measure the total number of seconds between now and when you want to run the function and sleep that number of seconds:

```
import datetime as DT
import time

while True:
    now = DT.datetime.now()
    target = DT.datetime.combine(DT.date.today(), DT.time(hour=8))
    if target < now:
        target += DT.timedelta(days=1)

    time.sleep((target-now).total_seconds())
    # do something
```

Comment: +1 for updating the answer with big warning about millisecond precision.

Comment: So I only want to run the code once a day so if I test within a range, how to I ensure it only happens once?

Comment: In that case I would arrange to sleep until it was time to run the function. I've updated the code to show what I mean.

Comment: This works well, thanks. Does this eat up a lot of computer cpu?

Comment: No, most of the time [it will be sleeping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/529034/190597) (or running the desired function).

Comment: I added a print statement where you added the do something comment and it printed it multiple times so it's actually not quite right

Comment: Hm. I don't see an error... Perhaps you have more than one script running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64608/discussion-between-user2242044-and-unutbu).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code simple, you can use the below code:

```
import datetime
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")  == '19:00:00':
        print ("it's time!")
```

Sleep is used to generate only 1 row per 1 second (without this you will print thousands of lines. Also it is worth to convert time to string.