# Wait for function to finish python

Tags: python, excel, function, python-2.7, wait

I have 2 functions:

1. `get_list` populates a list of site domains to excel sheet in column A
2. `get_traffic` calls API for each site and populates that to column B next to the relevant site domain

Problem is that function 2 (`get_traffic`) doesn't wait for function 1 (`get_list`) to finish before starting, and therefore I'm not getting the data I need.

My question is: how can I make a function wait for another function to finish before running?

code:

```
get_list(wb)
get_traffic(wb)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should always post the code that's you've tried to solve your problem. Also, this sounds like a problem where you'll need to use threading.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Won't that run the first function, then run the second?

Comment: How is `get_list` implemented? Does it use `threading` or similar internally, or does it call out to some kind of asynchronous API?

Answer (score 1):

Use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

```
t = threading.Thread(target=get_list, args=wb)
t.start()

while t.isAlive():
    pass

t = threading.Thread(target=get_traffic, args=wb)
t.start()
```

Comment: Does the loop hog CPU?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No, not really, but if you're worried, you can just use `time.sleep(0.01)` inside the loop, which should actually increase performance marginally.

Comment: Ew, of course [it will hog CPU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/529052/4403123). Using [`Event` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) would be better. Also, you forgot to start the threads. I don't get the point of using threads at all if you're running one function first, then the other.

Comment: @KSFT Oops, you're right, I forgot to start them. This is just a quick-and-dirty solution. It won't win any awards, but it'll solve OP's problem.