# What mistake am I making in this python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I trying to play around with multi-threading so I can better at it, but for some weird reason, my code doesn't want to follow the commands. It's suppose to go into a while loop and print, but it doesn't, and it's also not raising any errors, so which lines is the mistake on?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#
#
#
import random
import thread
import time
import sys
import os


def DisplayA(name,wait):
    while True:
        print 'Display: 1';time.sleep(wait)


def DisplayB(name,wait):
    while True:
        print 'Display: 2';time.sleep(wait)


def DisplayC(name,wait):
    while True:
        print 'Display: 3';time.sleep(wait)



thread.start_new_thread(DisplayA,('Display1',2))
thread.start_new_thread(DisplayB,('Display2',3))
thread.start_new_thread(DisplayC,('Display3',5))
```

Comment: This works correctly from my terminal ... ...

Comment: What is the output you're seeing? Nothing at all? Also, which version of Python, on which OS?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom:

```
while True:
   pass
```

The problem is that you're running off the bottom of your main program.  This terminates the entire execution session.

Comment: This is an endless loop which eats CPU.

Comment: Right ... it's merely a simple illustration.  Your response is a distinct improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and short solution:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Do not use pass in the while loop, because it eats CPU.
Expensive way of doing nothing.

If you want a more general solution, then you can import Tread from threading, then you can use join:

```
from threading import Thread
...

p1 = Thread(name="A", target=DisplayA, args=('Display1',2))
p2 = Thread(name="B", target=DisplayB, args=('Display2',3))
p3 = Thread(name="C", target=DisplayC, args=('Display3',5))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

This solution works also if the threads do not run endless, and your program can continue after the threads have finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do what Prune here suggested, or you can suspend the main thread after initiating DisplayA, DisplayB and DisplayC.

Comment: I am not using threading too much in python, but this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529034/python-pass-or-sleep-for-long-running-processes