# Impossible to kill ipython process

Tags: python, ipython

I use iPython on Windows.
I'm currently making a python script that can be stuck on socket reception (I have not implemented robustness on this part yet).

I'm trying every usual killing process key combinations (at least the ones I know) but iPython is stuck and I have to close and reopen it.
I tried Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+D, I don't know if there are other combinations.

Has anyone gone through this kind of problem ?

thank you

Alexandre

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Suppr ?

Comment: _that_ is super-annoying. I had workarounded this by doing the socket thing in a thread, and loop with a time.sleep() in the main, so CTRL+C works.

Comment: May I know which IDE you are using?

Comment: I'm on Windows, Ctrl+Alt+Suppr gives me access to the task manager, but still I would have to restart iPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some blocking operations (related to the operating system) cannot be interrupted properly (see [cannot interrupt lock.acquire() whereas I can interrupt time.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545612/cannot-interrupt-lock-acquire-whereas-i-can-interrupt-time-sleep))

I propose some approach which requires you to know what's going on in your code.

- run a thread with your code in it
- run a main with a try/except block for `KeyboardInterrupt`
- the handler of the exception shall release/close the socket, allowing the thread to finish.

I've created an example using thread locks for simplicity's sake. You can adapt this to sockets or whatever blocking resource:

```
import threading
import time,sys

l = threading.Lock()

def run():
    global l
    l.acquire()
    l.acquire()

t = threading.Thread(target=run)
t.start()

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("quitting")
        l.release()  # now thread can exit safely
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command:

```
exit
```

or try to restart the kernel.

Comment: what? but if OP cannot type CTRL something how can he/she type `exit`. Plus that is plain wrong. It doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to restart the kernel?

Comment: [Have you tried to turn it off and on again ?](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=it+crowd+have+you+tried+turning+it+off+and+on+again)

Comment: indeed, I don't have any possibility to type anything. Restarting iPython interpreter don't modify the behaviour, if I get stuck, it's for good :(